# How to get Document Name from DocumentReference in Firestore Python

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a document reference that I am retreiving from a query on my Firestore database. I want to use the DocumentReference as a query parameter for another query. However, when I do that, it says

```py
TypeError: sequence item 1: expected str instance, DocumentReference found
```

This makes sense, because I am trying to pass a DocumentReference in my update statement:

```py
db.collection("Teams").document(team).update("Dictionary here") # team is a DocumentReference
```

Is there a way to get the document name from a `DocumentReference`? Now before you mark this as duplicate: I tried looking at the docs [here](https://googleapis.dev/python/firestore/latest/document.html#), and the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63105418/return-values-from-documentreference-firestore), although the docs were so confusing and the question had no answer.

Any help is appreciated, Thank You in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes,split the `.refPath`.  The document "name" is *always* the last element after the split; something like lodash `_.last()` can work, or any other technique that identifies the last element in the array.

Note, btw, the refPath is the full path to the document.  This is *extremely* useful (as in: I use it a *lot*) when you find documents via `collectionGroup()` - it allows you to parse to find **parent** document(s)/collection(s) a particular document came from.

Also note: there is a pseudo-field `__name__` available.  (really an alias of `documentID()`).  In spite of it's name(s), it returns the FULL PATH (i.e. `refPath`) to the document **NOT** the documentID by itself.

Comment: That was very helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out - by doing `team.path.split("/")[1]` I could get the document name. Although this might not work for all firestore databases (like subcollections) so if anyone has a better solution, please go ahead. Thanks!